# JPackage update "PATH" environment variable

Tags: java, jpackage

when creating an installer (eg `.msi`) with `jpackage`, is there any way to update the `PATH` environment variable? This is quite important for console utilities.

Did not see anything about it in the [`jpackage` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html). Maybe one day it will be supported... but, meanwhile, is there any workaround? (I mean, besides asking the users to manually update `PATH` by themselves...)

Answer (score 4):

## Is It Possible?

YES.

Jpackage provides the ability to further customize the installer package built with [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/).

You'll have to use `--resource-dir` for that, as explained in [Packaging Tool User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6).

## Get Default main.wxs

Use the following command:

```
jpackage --input my_app [...] --temp "some/dir"
```

You'll have the following file structure generated:

```
\some\dir
   \config
      my_app.ico
      my_app.properties
      main.wxs
      MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl
      MsiInstallerStrings_ja.wxl
      MsiInstallerStrings_zh.wxl
      overrides.wxi
   \images
   \wixobj
```

Copy the `main.wxs` file into the directory of choice, e.g. `my_resource_dir`.

You aren't gonna need anything else, so you can safely delete it as well as the installation package generated.

## Change main.wxs to Append Your Installation Directory to the Path Variable

Change lines in `my_resource_dir/main.wxs`:

```
<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="!(loc.MainFeatureTitle)" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Shortcuts"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Files"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="FileAssociations"/>
</Feature>
```

to:

```
<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="!(loc.MainFeatureTitle)" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Shortcuts"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Files"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="FileAssociations"/>
  <Component Id="pathEnvironmentVariable" Guid="{YOUR_GUID}" KeyPath="yes" Directory="TARGETDIR">
    <Environment Id="MyPathVariable" Name="Path" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Action="set" System="no" Permanent="no" Part="last" Separator=";" />
  </Component>
</Feature>
```

Make sure to replace `YOUR_GUID` with the GUID generated with the [generator tool](https://www.guidgen.com/). For example: `[...] Guid="{607ea423-79e0-4866-9ed7-62005b88d225}"`

## Create the Installer that Appends to Path:

Run the following command:

```
jpackage --input my_app [...] --resource-dir "my_resource_dir" --verbose
```

In the log output you should see something similar to:

```
[...] Using custom main.wxs file [...]
```

## Result

The installer built now appends your INSTALLDIR to the Path on installation and removes it during uninstall.

Comment: thx! I ll try it out, and see if I manage to get it to work

Comment: Let me know if you have some issues with it, I'll try to help